# Gridview multiline Textview cut off

Tags: android, gridview, textview

I have a `GridView` and each cell has an `ImageView` with `TextView` under it.  Unfortunately if the `TextView` has more than one line the text gets cut off.  I have tried everything but I cant find a solution.

It seems that the row height of the `GridView` is the problem and not the actual text because you can see half of the text in the `Textview`.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Acronyms.class));
        }

    });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Integer[] iconImg = { 
            R.drawable.acronyms, R.drawable.acronyms,
            R.drawable.acronyms
    };
    private String[] iconTitle = {
            "Acronyms", "Cardiac Strips",
            "Test 3"
    };

    public int getCount() {
        return iconImg.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) { 
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.icon, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
            textView.setText(iconTitle[position]);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
            imageView.setImageResource(iconImg[position]);

        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#a3e6ff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="25"
        android:text="Example"
        android:textColor="#248fb7"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:typeface="serif" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="15dp" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my icon.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_icon_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_image"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/icon_text"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Samples Samples"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is a screenshot:
[image: Multi-line cut off]

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem! Incredibly annoying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[EDIT1]**

You could try using a RelativeLayout instead of a Linear Layout for the icon.xml.

If this doesnt work then I would then move to a static height TextView.  From looking at your screenshot, it looks like you will always use the same image, and the text is either going to be 1 line or 2.  Just make the text height static to allow for 2 lines.

**[ORIGINAL]**
I think the problem is in your linear layout definition for your icon.xml.  In your definition, you have the layout having "match_parent" as the width and height parameters.  You should, since these are to essentially be subviews within the gridview be "wrap_content".  Here is what I think it should be

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
    android:id="@+id/grid_icon_layout"     
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"     
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon_image"         
        android:layout_width="90dp"         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />       

    <TextView android:id="@+id/icon_text"         
        android:layout_width="90dp"         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"         
        android:maxLines="2"         
        android:singleLine="false"         
        android:text="Samples Samples"         
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"         
        android:textSize="15dp"         
        android:typeface="serif" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried this and I am still getting the same result though.

Comment: I ended up having to explicitly setting the height of the TextView in the icon.xml file.  I tried relative and linear and no luck.  The GridView must have trouble rendering since the first item in the grid is a single line, it probably goes by that items height.

Comment: I think that what happens is that the overall sub-layouts end up with differing heights within the gridview (i.e. each grid item may have a different height).  I actually dont know how the background code of the GridView is programmed, but I do wonder if you were to define your 2 line text item first, if it would size appropriately???  It may have something to do with it using the first one for the height dimension and never updating afterwards!!!

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking too.  Since the first item is a single, then it uses that height for the row. I just tested it and it's confirmed!  When set to `wrap_content` it uses the first item as a reference for the dimensions. I set the text to fill up two rows and the TextView doesnt get cut off

Answer (score 6):

I resolved using, when i define it

```
    TextView.setLines(2);
```

in the xml the textview is

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change ConstraintLayout for LinearLayout.
Make sure you are using ConstraintLayout and if possible change by LinearLayout. For long texts, Constraint is not very good.